# How can I copy GitLab-generated test artifacts to a Box directory via JAVA?

Tags: copy, gitlab-ci

I would like to copy my Test Output from /test-oputput/report/index.html to Box directory. I am using Gitlab and in test Stage I generated Assets but failed to copy to box.

Is there any way to access artifacts via JAVA?
If not in such cases can gitlab access Box directory which is accessible via TOKEN only?

Thanks

I have tried copying file using JAVA code from test-output/report/index.html, and it is working as expected but as I mentioned it is not working when it PUSHed to GIT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to resolve this issue by making directory visible in Git Server.